# Why do I need tortoise SVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I just installed Visual SVN server and visual SVN and got a message that I do not have tortoise SVN installed so some features are not available.

Why do I need tortoise SVN?

edit0:

From: http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/

*In order to setup VisualSVN you should download and install TortoiseSVN. The current version of VisualSVN is compatible with any version of TortoiseSVN 1.6.x (excluding nightly TortoiseSVN builds numbered as 1.6.99.x). It's recommended to use the latest stable TortoiseSVN 1.6.9 build.*

So WTF does VisualSVN Server work with ?

Comment: Who gave you that message? VisualSVN?

Comment: at the end of the visualsvn install, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VisualSVN Server is Subversion server with management tools and additional modules, such Windows authentication and authorization. You can use any Subversion client to work with VisualSVN Server. Subversion command line client (svn.exe) is already included in VisualSVN Server.

TortoiseSVN is Subversion plug-in to Windows Explorer. It's open-source product.

VisualSVN (Client) is Subversion integration add-in to Microsoft Visual Studio. It gives you ability to work with Subversion without leaving you IDE. VisualSVN (Client) uses TortoiseSVN for most commands. That's big benefit of VisualSVN (Client) since you get the same Subversion UI in Visual Studio as in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 5):

Not used it. But from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualSVN), it seems VisualSVN is a Visual Studio add-in that wraps around TortoiseSVN - a popular subversion client. So its a dependency, that must be installed.

But are you sure it doesn't come as part of the VisualSVN distribution ? it should.

Update:
[Source](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/tortoisesvn/)

> VisualSVN uses TortoiseSVN for most of
>   the dialogs. But "Add Solution"
>   wizard, "Get Solution" command and
>   Visual Studio integration (status
>   icons, transparent file operations
>   etc.) do not depend on TortoiseSVN.

Comment: VisualSVN *client* wraps around Tortoise. *Server*, to my knowledge, does not and it wouldn't make much sense. Strange.

Comment: When I went here to install subversion http://subversion.apache.org/ I ended up here http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows and installed visualsvn server assuming that was the serverside part and the visual svn was the vis studio integration to talk to the visualsvn server

Comment: so what is the client that you use to access the server component ? If its VisualSVN Client, I think you'd be bound to TortoiseSVN. See update.